# Increment value of one element of an JSON array of objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON, which contains id and points. if the ID matches, i need to increase with 1. IF the id does not match i need to push to a new empty array

Here what I have tried. but it is not working

```
var points = [{
  id: 1,
  point: 0
}, {
  id: 2,
  point: 0
}, {
  id: 3,
  point: 1
}]

var data = {
  id: 1
}

if (!(points.length)) {
  points.push(data)
} else {
  if (points.find(e => e.id === data.id)) {
    var m = points.find(e => e)
    console.log(m.id)
    m.point+= 1
  } else {
    points.push(data)
  }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing like a _"JSON array"_. `points` is an array of objects.

Comment: thanks corrected it

Comment: So what's not working?

Comment: What is not working? I see its working

Comment: `m = points.find(e => e)` that is wrong. You need to do the same test in the callback as in the `if` condition. Of course, you should rewrite it so to have to do that only once.

Comment: @MunimMunna It only works if the id in `data` is the same as the id of the first element in `points`

Comment: Yeah that is the problem

Answer (score 2):

You're always increasing the first element of the array

```
var m = points.find(e => e)
=>
var m = points.find(e => e.id === data.id)
```

`find` need a predicate that return true or false given an element. In the first line, it always return the element itself which is a truthy value. So the first element is return

Comment: Because  `find` need a predicate that return true or false given an element. In the first line, it always return the element itself which is a truthy value. If this solvers your problem, can you please accept the answer (white check mark below the up/down-vote buttons) to indicate this question is answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method on array returns a value and not `boolean` as you maybe are trying to use in this case. It'll return `undefined` if no value matches.

Also you don't really need the outer `if` and nest one more inside it.

```js
var points = [{
  id: 1,
  point: 0
}, {
  id: 2,
  point: 0
}, {
  id: 3,
  point: 1
}]

var data = {
  id: 1
}

let temp = points.find(e => e.id === data.id)
if (temp != undefined) { // This is just for understanding. `undefined` inside `if` will give false. So you can use `if(!temp)`
  temp.point+= 1
} else {
  points.push(data)
}

console.log(points);
```

Comment: `undefined` is a falsy value which will evaluate as `false`, hence there's no need to explicitly test for `undefined`. The real solution in your answer is unmentioned and unexplained.

Comment: @Andreas I'm testing it explicitly just to explain that it'll return `undefined` if no value is found. Added a comment for that. In the question `find` method is used twice with `if` and again inside the `if` which is actually not needed. [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is more appropriate method to use with conditionals than `find`.

Answer (score 1):

The new data needs a point property, and you could clean the code up a little to be clearer about intent...

```js
var points = [{
  id: 1,
  point: 0
}, {
  id: 2,
  point: 0
}, {
  id: 3,
  point: 1
}]

var data = {
  id: 1
}

// we have a data object.  if it's new (not found in points) add it with a point count of 0
// if it exists (we find it in points array) increment point for the existing element

let matchingPoint = points.find(p => p.id === data.id);
if (!matchingPoint) {
    data.point = 0;
    points.push(data);
} else {
    matchingPoint.point += 1;
}
console.log(points)
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating an object:

```
tagObject = {};
tagObject['contentID'] = [];  // adding an entry to the above tagObject
tagObject['contentTypes'] = []; // same explanation as above
tagObject['html'] = [];
```

Now below is the occurrences entry which I am addding to the above tag Object..

ES 2015 standards: function () {} is same as () => {}

```
      let found = Object.keys(tagObject).find(
            (element) => {
                return element === matchWithYourValueHere;
            });

      tagObject['occurrences'] = found ? tagObject['occurrences'] + 1 : 1;
```

this will increase the count of a particular object key..